# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Analytics' not found when using on controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-analytics

I'm using spatie/laravel-analytics everything is working fine when I'm using it on route.php but when I try to use it in a controller it throws this error! Kind of strange! This is my Controller Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Spatie\Analytics\Period;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Question;
use App\Contact;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        // $questions = Question::whereNull('answer')->get();
        // $messages = Contact::where('status', false)->get();


        //Data from Google Analytics
        $totalVisitors = Analytics::fetchTotalVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7));
        // $mostVisitedPages = Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages(Period::days(7), $maxResults = 5);
        // $topReferrers = Analytics::fetchTopReferrers(Period::days(7), $maxResults = 5);
        // $topBrowsers = Analytics::fetchTopBrowsers(Period::days(7), $maxResults = 5);

        return $totalVisitors;

        return view('admin.admin-dashboard', compact(
            'messages', 'questions', 'totalVisitors', 'mostVisitedPages', 'topReferrers', 'topBrowsers'
        ));
    }
}
```

Also my route.php code is :

```
use Spatie\Analytics\Period;

Route::get('/test', function() {


    // Data from Google Analytics
    $totalVisitors = Analytics::fetchTotalVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7));
    $mostVisitedPages = Analytics::fetchMostVisitedPages(Period::days(7), $maxResults = 5);
    $topReferrers = Analytics::fetchTopReferrers(Period::days(7), $maxResults = 5);
    $topBrowsers = Analytics::fetchTopBrowsers(Period::days(7), $maxResults = 5);

    return $totalVisitors;


});
```

=

Comment: Your controller is in a custom namespace. So unless you `use Analytics` (or `Spatie\Analytics`), it will look for the class in the same namespace. You can work around this by using the fully qualified class name, e.g. `\Spatie\Analytics::fetchTotalVisitors......`

Comment: You are life saver! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

On the controller you can try this after the namespace line:

```
use Analytics;
```

Answer (score 1):

On the controller use these namespaces as below:-
`use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Analytics;
use Spatie\Analytics\Period;`